# Mongrel: how to process erb in .rhtml file

Tags: ruby, erb, mongrel, rhtml

I am trying to serve up static content for some web development, with a few lines of erb to simulate what the real server will do. I already did this with WEBrick here: http://ceronio.net/2011/06/nice-web-server-script-to-server-any-directory-using-webrick, but now I want to do this with Mongrel.

My code so far is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongrel'
Mongrel::DirHandler.add_mime_type('.rhtml', 'text/html')
server = Mongrel::HttpServer.new("localhost", 2000)
server.register("/", Mongrel::DirHandler.new(Dir::pwd))
server_thread = server.run
server_thread.join
```

But when I access my index.rhtml file, it does not process the content in the <% %> tags, but just passes the file as is to the browser.

With WEBrick, nothing additional was required. What do I need to do here to get the server-side Ruby code processed in the .rhtml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the code of the DirHandler class in Mongrel, it seems that this class is not made for applying any processing to a file, but just serving it up as is.

It seems the only way to do this in Mongrel would be to modify DirHandler or write your own HttpHandler.